# Change the script path in an Apache proxy handler

Tags: apache-2.4, docker, reverse-proxy, apache2, mod-proxy

I'm developing my application with 2 containers: **apache** and **php-fpm**.

Apache serves requests, and delegates PHP execution to the php-fpm container in its vhost:

```
    <FilesMatch .php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://myapp-php-fpm:9000"
    </FilesMatch>
```

The two containers share a single volume that contains the application code.

The location of that volume is different in each of the containers:

- apache mounts the app code volume at `/home/wwwdata/myapp`
- php-fpm mounts the app code volume at `/var/task`

How can I change the script path that Apache sends to the php-fpm container, so that it matches where the volume is mounted in the php-fpm container?

---

I can do this in nginx by setting `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and `DOCUMENT_ROOT`:

```
        location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
          fastcgi_pass myapp-php-fpm:9000;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
          include fastcgi_params;

          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/task/$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/task;

          internal;
        }
```

but I haven't been able to replicate this behavior in Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ProxyFCGISetEnvIf` to set the `SCRIPT_FILENAME`:

```
    <FilesMatch .php$>
        ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" SCRIPT_FILENAME "/var/task%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://myapp-php-fpm:9000"
    </FilesMatch>
```